# Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong in this C program?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, printf, fopen

I am trying to write all that is printed in the program as output into a file named "abcd.txt" and whenever i run the program, it runs fine and exits but the file "abcd.txt" has no written content in it.

```
    void main()
{       
    struct date
    {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;

    };

    struct details
    {
        char name[20];
        int price;
        int code;
        int qty;
        struct date mfg;
    };

    struct details item[50];
    int n,i;
    FILE *fp;

    getch();


    fprintf(stderr,"Enter number of items:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    fflush(stdin);
    fp = fopen( "abcd.txt", "w+" ); // Open file for writing

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        fflush(stdin);
        fprintf(stderr,"Item name:");     
        scanf("%[^\n]",item[i].name);

        fflush(stdin);
        fprintf(stderr,"Item code:");
        scanf("%d",&item[i].code);
        fflush(stdin);

        fprintf(stderr,"Quantity:");
        scanf("%d",&item[i].qty);
        fflush(stdin);

        fprintf(stderr,"price:");
        scanf("%d",&item[i].price);
        fflush(stdin);

        fprintf(stderr,"Manufacturing date(dd-mm-yyyy):");
        scanf("%d-%d-%d",&item[i].mfg.day,&item[i].mfg.month,&item[i].mfg.year);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    fprintf(stderr,"             *****  INVENTORY *****\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"S.N.|    NAME           |   CODE   |  QUANTITY |  PRICE  |MFG.DATE\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        fprintf(stderr,"%d     %-15s        %-d          %-5d     %-5d     %d/%d/%d\n",i+1,item[i].name,item[i].code,item[i].qty,item[i].price,
                  item[i].mfg.day,item[i].mfg.month,item[i].mfg.year);
    fprintf(stderr,"------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    fclose(fp);
    getch();
}
```

These are the errors the compiler is telling me : 'Code Final.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Qsmrf\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\qasimproject\Code Final\Code Final\Debug\Code Final.exe', Symbols loaded.

'Code Final.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

'Code Final.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

'Code Final.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

'Code Final.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.

The program '[3256] Code Final.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: don't use `void main`, `fflush(stdin)` etc. and proved minimal working code that demonstrate your problem.

Comment: this line: fflush(stdin); per the standard is undefined behaviour and not actually implemented in all OSs.

Comment: regarding this line: fp = fopen( "abcd.txt", "w+" );  any i/o statement, like fopen, should have the returned value checked to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this line: scanf("%d-%d-%d",&item[i].mfg.day,&item[i].mfg.month,&item[i].mfg.year); has a few problems. 1) the returned value from scanf needs to be checked to assure all the input/conversions were successful 2) to skip left over white space, like newlines, the format string should have a leading space.  These same considerations should be applied to all the calls to scanf

Comment: after reading 'n', the code (probably) should malloc the memory for the struct details *item , rather than hardcoding a fixed size of the array of items.  What if 'n' were larger than 50?

Comment: Guys i am really confused now, i have tried everything that you guys have told me to do but still no luck. It gives me even more errors. I know i am doing something really stupid in the code as error since i am a hopeless newbie. Please could anybody tell me what is really needed to be done by making the changes yourself in the code because i really have tried everything. :/

Answer (score 2):

This is because you don't write anything to `fp`. Instead of `fprintf(stderr,"Item name:")`, use something like

```
fprintf(fp,"Item name:");
```

Also make sure file opened succesfully and close it only in the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)
```

The stream should be your file to which you want to write data. Here it is `fp` but we don't see anything being written to your file.Like

```
fprintf(fp,"price");
```

Answer (score 1):

More than one thing to notice here.

1. change `void main()` to `int main()`, add a `return 0` at end.
2. Move your structure defitions outside `main()` and is possible, to some header file, which you can include. Good practice.
3. `p = fopen( "abcd.txt", "w+" );` after this, check for the success of `fopen()`. if success, then usze the `fp`.
4. `fprintf(stderr,"price:");` this will redirect all your output data to `stderr`, not to the `fp`.  Change `stderr` with `fp` if you want the output to be placed in the specified file.
5. after reading the data, use `fprintf(fp, ...);` to output (write) the data to file. [This point is kind of *redundant* to point 4.]
6. you have multiple `fclose(fp);`. remove all others [present inside loop] and retain the one just before the end [possible `return` statement.]

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to write into the file descriptor you opened not stderr. 
   eg: it should be `fprintf(fp, "abcd");` not `fprintf(stderr, "adcd");`
2. You are closing the fp inside the for loop. You should close it at the end to the main. So remove the statement in the for loop.
3. Even then the output is not going to take the values you entered. Since you are reading the values but not storing in the file. For that you need to store the values into the file using fprintf() in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not Using the file pointer for that corresponding file. Then you open that with the w+ it will truncate the content in it.

Then use the fp to wrte in file instead of stderr. Then you are using the fclose two times.

```
fprintf(stderr,"             *****  INVENTORY *****\n");
```

From this line you have to use the fp for storing in the file instead of stderr.

Comment: the open mode 'w+' says to open the file for append, not truncate.  To truncate, the mode would need to be "w"

Comment: @user3629249 Have you read the man page for a fopen function.     w+  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not exist, otherwise it is  truncated.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.